# ¿Como puedo borrar una variable de un PHP en otro PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hasta el momento tengo un código con esto

```html
 <form action="Eliminar2.php" method="post" target="_blank" action="Eliminar2.php">
<input type="text" name="ident" id="ident" value="" placeholder="Nro. Identificacion" required="required" /> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" value="buscar" name="buscar" />
```

Y del otro lado para querer borrar, tengo esta parte

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "post") {
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
            <center><button onclick="alert ('Registro eliminado')" value="eliminar" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button></center>
            <center><input type="button" value="Cancelar" /></center>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$eliminar = $_POST['eliminar'];
    if ($eliminar == TRUE) {
        $ident = $_POST["ident"];
        $res = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE ID_Usuario='$ident'");
    }
?>
```

Pero no me borra nada, ayuda porfavor

Comment: Falta contexto en tu pregunta. No nos dices si mandas los datos desde un `form`, si hay un elemento con `name="eliminar"`. Si la consulta SQL se cumple con ese criterio. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` en tu contexto?

Comment: Una disculpa, como soy nuevo en esto no sabía bien, mando datos desde este form y lo recibo en el segundo codigo.
       **<form action="Eliminar2.php" method="post" target="_blank" action="Eliminar2.php">
            <center><font color="black"><h3>Introduce el ID del registro que deseas eliminar:</h3></font></center>
            <input type="hidden" name="vienedelform" value="si" />
            <input type="text" name="ident" id="ident" value="" placeholder="Nro. Identificacion" required="required" />
            <br>
            <br>**

Comment: Esta condición nunca se cumplirá: `if ($eliminar == TRUE) {` porque en tu `form` no hay ningún elemento con `name="eliminar"` que tenga un valor. Debes replantear la lógica.

Comment: ¿Y si arriba tengo un boto? Algo así
<html>
    <body>
      <center><button onclick="alert ('Registro eliminado')" value="eliminar" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button></center>
            <center><input type="button" value="Cancelar" /></center>
    </body>
</html>

Y despues el PHP
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$eliminar = $_POST['eliminar'];
    if ($eliminar == TRUE) {
        $ident = $_POST["ident"];
        $res = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE ID_Usuario='$ident'");
    }
?>

Comment: ¿Explica qué entiendes por *arriba*? Si ese botón no está dentro del `form` no se enviará con él. De hecho, tu código sigue siendo incompleto, no se ve el `form` completo, no se ve por qué medio se envía, si por un botón, ni qué valores tiene dicho botón. Pulsa en [edit] y pon el contexto completo, con un código por partes es complicado ayudar. Como te sugerí más arriba **pon un `var_dump($_POST);`  y dinos qué muestra**. Así podrás ver todo lo que se está enviando.

Comment: Ya lo intente modificar, disculpa la molestia

Comment: Es erróneo meter ese `body` donde lo tienes, debes revisar un poco las estructura de los documentos HTML. Convendría que estudies también un poco sobre Ajax en cuanto sea posible. Pero, yendo al problema que ahora nos ocupa, observa esto: `<input type="submit" value="buscar" name="buscar" />`  el `name` que hay asociado es `buscar`, y en PHP tú estás verificando `eliminar`. Debes cambiar la lógica como te dije, sea cambiando el `name` y `value` de ese `input`, sea cambiando en el `$_POST`  en PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que cuando mandas un `form` cada dato de los `input` se asocia en un array cuya clave será lo que tengas en la etiqueta `name` de cada `input`.

Por tanto, según tu `form` actual, esto nunca se cumplirá:

```
$eliminar = $_POST['eliminar'];
if ($eliminar == TRUE) {
```

Dado que en `$_POST['eliminar']` no hay nada, ningún elemento tiene asociado un `name="eliminar"` en tu `form`, el botón que hace el submit tiene un `name="buscar"`  y un valor también igual a `buscar`.

Entonces, para que se cumpla debes ponerlo así en PHP:

```
$eliminar = $_POST['buscar'];
if ($eliminar == TRUE) {
```

Aunque no es muy lógico esto, otra opción es cambiar el botón en el `form`:

```
<input type="submit" value="eliminar" name="eliminar" />
```

Si haces esto, el código funcionará como lo tienes inicialmente:

```
$eliminar = $_POST['eliminar'];
    if ($eliminar == TRUE) {
```

Aunque es un código incómodo, porque comparas una cadena contra un booleano (`TRUE`), funciona en PHP, no sabemos hasta cuando. En otro lenguaje estrictamente tipado (y PHP va hacia ello), esa comparación resultará en un error, porque `$eliminar` es una cadena y la estás comparando contra un valor booleano que es `TRUE`. Aunque PHP sea permisivo, aplica un estilo de programación estricto desde le principio, comparando cadenas contra cadenas, y booleanos contra booleanos (ver mejor sugerencia).

#### Mejor sugerencia

Pero lo más lógico de todo es que des un nombre genérico al botón (vamos a llamarlo `action`)  y que verifiques su valor, para decidir según él, que acción debe ejecutarse, si `eliminar`, `insertar`, `actualizar`, etc.

Algo así:

**En el formulario**

```
<input type="submit" value="eliminar" name="action" />
```

**En PHP:**

```
#Empezaremos a usar fusión de null
$action = $_POST['action'] ?? NULL;
if ($action === 'eliminar') {
```

Así tu código es más lógico en todos los sentidos.

OJO: En cualquier caso, tu `form` debe estar correctamente cerrado, o no funcionará nunca:

```
<form>
    Aquí todos los inputs y botones del form
</form>
```

#### Post-Data

Hay otras técnicas que deberías implementar:

- Usar ternarios para recuperar los datos de `$_POST`
- Usar consultas preparadas para dar seguridad a tu código

Simplemente lo señalo, sin ahondar en eso, porque se aleja del propósito de tu pregunta y porque tu código tiene aún más deficiencias que deberías corregir, como te señalé en un comentario (convendría que uses Ajax, y que coloques correctamente el `body` en tu HTML).